# Getting value of an item in json

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I want to get value of option key from an json,
eg: the array below should return 12
I have tried the following code but I always get 'Undefined array key 0'

```
    {{ $question->options[0]['option'] }}
```

the data is stored in a json column of mysql database, the laravel model is Question and column is options I can get the column but i am not able to get the value of option key after getting the data in the column, i don't want to use php foreach

```
{
    "1": {
        "option": "12",
        "correct": "1"
    }
}


Array ( [1] => Array ( [option] => 12 [correct] => 1 ) ) 1
```

Comment: The key in your example is "1", not "0"

Comment: Even {{ $question->options[1]['option'] }} doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got, I was able to do it this way after thorough trial

```
array_values($question->options)[0]['option']
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must parse data with `json_decode`

```
$question ='{
            "1": {
                "option": "12",
                "correct": "1"
            }
        }';
        $toArray = json_decode($question);
        print_r($toArray->{1}->option); // Accessing invalid object properties
    }
```